# Want to extract text from a text or pdf file as different paragraphs

Tags: python, text-extraction, corpus, expert-system

**Check the following text piece**

IN THE HIGH COURT OF GUJARAT AT AHMEDABAD
R/CRIMINAL APPEAL NO.  251 of 2009

FOR APPROVAL AND SIGNATURE:

HONOURABLE MR.JUSTICE R.P.DHOLARIA

==========================================================
1     Whether Reporters of Local Papers may be allowed to see the judgment ?
2     To be referred to the Reporter or not ?
3     Whether their Lordships wish to see the fair copy of the judgment ?
4     Whether this case involves a substantial question of law as to the interpretation of the Constitution of India or any order made thereunder ?
========================================================== STATE OF GUJARAT,S M RAO,FOOD INSPECTOR,OFFICE OF THE Versus DHARMESHBHAI NARHARIBHAI GANDHI ========================================================== Appearance: MS HB PUNANI, APP (2) for the Appellant(s) No. 1 MR DK MODI(1317) for the Opponent(s)/Respondent(s) No. 1 ==========================================================
CORAM: HONOURABLE MR.JUSTICE R.P.DHOLARIA

Date : 12/03/2019

**ORAL JUDGMENT**
1. The appellant State of Gujarat has 
preferred the present appeal under section 378(1)
(3) of the Code of Criminal Procedure, 1973 
against the judgment and order of acquittal dated 
*Page  1 of  12
R/CR.A/251/2009*                                                                                                 JUDGMENT
17.11.2008 rendered by learned 2nd Additional 
Civil Judge and Judicial Magistrate, First Class, 
Nadiad in Food Case No.1 of 2007.

2. The short facts giving rise to the 
   present appeal are that on 10.11.2006 at about 
   18.00 hours, the complainant visited the place of 
   the respondent accused situated at Juna 
   Makhanpura, Rabarivad, Nadiad along with panch 
   witness and the respondent was found dealing in 
   provisional items. The complainant identified 
   himself as a Food Inspector and after giving 
   intimation in Form No.6 has purchased muddamal 
   sample of mustard seeds in the presence of the 
   panchas for the purpose of analysis. Thereafter, 
   the complainant Food Inspector has divided the 
   said sample in equal three parts and after 
   completing formalities of packing and sealing 
   obtained signatures of the vendor and panchas and 
   out of the said three parts, one part was sent to 
   the Public Analyst, Vadodara for analysis and 
   remaining two parts were sent to the Local Health 
   Authority, Gandhinagar. Thereafter, the Public 
   Analyst forwarded his report. In the said report, 
   it is stated that the muddamal sample of mustard 
   seeds is misbranded which is in breach of the 
   provisions of the Food Adulteration Act, 1954 
   (for short “the Act”) and the Rules framed 
   thereunder. It is alleged that, therefore, the 
   sample of mustard seeds was misbranded and, 
   thereby, the accused has committed the offence. 
   **Page  2 of  12
   R/CR.A/251/2009*                                                                                                 JUDGMENT*
   Hence, the complaint came to be lodged against 
   the respondent accused.

I want to be able to write a program such that it follows the given constraints. Be wary of the fact that this is only a single file i have like 40k files and it should run on all the files. All the files have some difference but the basic format for every file is the same.

Constraints.

1. It should start the text extraction process from after the "metadata" . Metadata is the data about the file from the starting of the file i.e " In the high court of gujarat" till Oral Judgment. In all the files i have , there are various POINTS after the  string ends. So i need all these points as a separate paragraph ( see the text has 2 points , i need it in different paragraphs ).
2. Check the lines in italics, these are the panes in the text/pdf file. I need to remove these as these donot have any meaning to the text content i want.
3. These files are both available in TEXT or PDF format so i can use either. But i am new to python so i dont know how and where to start. I just have basic knowledge in python.
4. This data is going to be made into a "corpus" for further processes in building a huge expert system so you know what needs to be done i hope.

Answer (score 0):

1. Read the official [python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/contents.html)!
2. Start with python's basic [`str` type and its methods](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str). One of its methods, `find`, will find substrings in your text.
3. Use the python slicing notation to extract the portion of text you need, e.g.

```py
text = """YOUR TEXT HERE..."""
meta_start = 'In the high court of gujarat'
meta_end = 'ORAL JUDGMENT'
pos1 = text.find(meta_start)
pos2 = text.find(meta_end)
if pos2 > pos1 and pos1 > -1:
    # text is found, extract it
    text1 = text[meta_start + len(meta_start):meta_end - 1]
```

4. After that, you can go ahead and save your extracted text to a database.

Of course, a better and more complicated solution would be to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re), but that's another story -- try finding the right way for yourself!

As to italics and other text formatting, you won't ever be able to mark it out in plain text (unless you have some 'meta' markers, like e.g. [i] tags).

Comment: Thing is i don't know what is the text that i need to find. I need anything and everything that is written in those points and it can start or end with anything.

i just want all the points in the file to be separated as different paragraphs , skipping the metadata altogether .

Comment: Not sure what you mean here by 'points' - specific text markers? To filter out unnecessary data you will need some text markers all the same. Breaking into paragraphs is easy enough, use the `split()` method of `str`. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Points as in paragraphs followed by numeral bullets. Here
Text after ORAL JUDGEMENT 1. .... 2.... , 1 is first point , 2 is second point and so on.

Comment: Also , a file can have many points , or a single point.
And a file can also have sub-points under points. And those are to be clubbed under a single point 
Example. Suppose if a file has point structure as follows 

1
2
2.1
2.2
3
3.1
3.1.1
3.1.2 

Then the output file should have points as paragraphed as a single point 

1
2
3
and so on.

Comment: OK. What you need is [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=re#module-re). Construct a regex, e.g. "(^(\d+\.)+)(\s*)(.*)" and extract your paragraphs with `re.findall()` or `re.finditer()`. PS. The given regex will work if your paragraph number start always at a new line; if not, just remove the "^" sign.